# asp Event tied to button in gridview not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview, updatepanel

I know similar questions have come up elsewhere, but after looking at everything I could find nothing's helped. I've been banging my head against this for hours now. I have an asp:button in a gridview that just won't fire; no error, nothing else fails, this event just doesn't get called.

Other buttons on the same page (not in a gridview) work, and other buttons in gridviews on other pages, set up identically, do work. I'm missing something, but what?

Relevant .aspx (summarised):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="thisPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.thisPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<link href="../Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="thisPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="thisGV" onrowcommand="thisGV_RowCommand">
   <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID"/>
    <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Button runat="server" ID="confirmButton" CommandName="confirm" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' Text="Confirm" />
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
   <EmptyDataTemplate>
    No records found for those details, please try again.
   </EmptyDataTemplate>
  </asp:GridView>
 </ContentTemplate>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  });
 </script>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Relevant aspx.cs (summarised):

```
public partial class Form8Exams : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 int ID = 0;
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
   loadGV();
  }
 }

 protected void thisGV_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
  //A bunch of things that don't get called
  //Let me be clear; I've tested, and as far as I can tell
  //it's not that the things here fail to work, but that
  //this function doesn't get called at all.
 }

 protected void loadGV()
 {
  if (!Page.IsPostBack) // Added in desperation, but no change with or without.
  {
   hwHelper helper = new hwHelper();
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt = helper .dtget(ID, "");
   if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
    thisGV.DataSource = dt;
    thisGV.DataBind();
    thisPanel.Update();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

The master page wraps the whole thing in a form and adds a scriptmanager etc; another page (sharing the same master page) works with this setup.

I've tried variants using OnClick and OnCommand on the button itself, with no change. Note that the page loads correctly in the first place, this gridview does get populated etc. I've compared everything else I can think of against the page with the working updatepanel>gridview>button, and I can't see what I've missed. Help!

Comment: Did you try it outside of the UpdatePanel?

Comment: Tested your snippet, it works.... How are you testing that `thisGV_RowCommand` is reached.

Comment: @VDWWD - Oooh, hang on a second, you may have it.

I'd tried by seeing if the function was doing what it should (some SQL), but the data wasn't changing (and no error was being thrown). So I whacked a literal on the page and checked for updates, but saw no change, so "event not firing".

With your prompting, it occurred this could be two things; page not reloaded (so literal changing but not presented), and an issue with the SQL (not an error, but not actually making changes either). Tested and, sure enough, literal _was_ changing, so event _was_ firing. Off to fix the SQL, cheers!